# adding a day date in time.struct_time object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need your help with my current code. I want to add the next day date using with `time.struct_time` object, but I have got no idea how to do this after I have stored the string in the `self.epg_time_1` list.

Example:
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=17, tm_min=00, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=53, tm_isdst=-1)

To this:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=17, tm_min=00, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=53, tm_isdst=-1)[/python]
```

If I want to add the next day, I would have to readd the same code that I have already been using:

```
epg_time_1_days = time.strftime("%d")
epg_time_1_months = time.strftime("%m")
epg_time_1_year = time.strftime("%Y")
epg_time_1_days = int(time.strftime("%d") + 1)
epg_time_1_days = str(today_day)
epg_time_1_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
epg_time_1_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
half_hour_date = str(epg_time_1_days + "/" + epg_time_1_months + "/" + epg_time_1_year + " " + "17:30PM")
self.epg_time_1.append(half_hour_date)
```

Here is the code:

```
half_hour_date = ''.join(str(x) for x in self.epg_time_1)
epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour_date, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
```

Output for `half_hour_date`:

```
22/02/2018 5:00PM
```

Output for `epg_time_1`:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=17, tm_min=00, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=53, tm_isdst=-1)
```

I don't want to re-add the same code that I have already wrote it. If you can show me an example how I could use a short simple code to add the date to the next day date using with `time.struct_time` object, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) instead?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> d = datetime.today()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 22, 16, 25, 1, 596038)
>>> tomorrow = (d + timedelta(days=1))
>>> tomorrow
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 23, 16, 25, 1, 596038)
>>> d.day, tomorrow.day
(22, 23)
```